# Obtaining bearer token for Sharepoint REST API calls

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest

Our scenario is following:

1. User logs in through SSO (using Azure AD) to our website.
2. On the site we have a page that will show links to some documents from SharePoint.
3. The page will query SharePoint 2013 on prem through its REST API to get a list of those documents.

My problem is obtaining the Bearer token that I would use for my REST API calls.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx#Files

I would very much appreciate a code example on how to obtain the Bearer token.

Comment: Do you know how to setup SharePoint on-premise to support bearer token authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain an Azure AD access token through ADAL.
There is a official JavaScript library (ADAL JS) with documentation hosted on GitHub:

[ADAL for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)